# SQL nested queries and SUM()

Tags: sql, sqlite

Currently I am working on a homework question and am stuck. 
The question is: Display the manager of the employee with the oldest project start date.

The tables that I feel are usable are
**DEPARTMENT**
department char
manager
location
dno

**EMPLOYEE**
emp_id
title
bdate 
gender
dno

**PROJECT**
emp_id
start_date
days_duration

I know that the answer should be Nick_Fury and that the start date is wrong but should be 1-jan-12. We have to use the MIN() function which should be MIN(start_date). We can't use JOIN as we havn't be told about it yet.

```
'SELECT manager
FROM DEPARTMENT
WHERE dno IN
                    (SELECT dno
                    FROM EMPLOYEE
                    WHERE emp_id IN
                                            (SELECT MIN(start_date)
                                            FROM project
                                            )
                    );'
```

When I run it nothing comes back. I know there appears to be a problem with the MIN(start_date). My thoughts on how it is done are as follows.
Find the managers and then the dno, link the dno to the employee table, then use the emp_id to link to the project table which should pull it. But it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Focusing just on the project table, how would you get the row that has the minimum start date?

Answer (score 1):

Within those 2 minutes I figured it out with

```
SELECT manager
FROM DEPARTMENT
WHERE dno IN
                    (SELECT dno
                    FROM EMPLOYEE
                    WHERE emp_id IN
                                            (SELECT emp_id
                                            FROM project
                                            WHERE start_date =(SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM PROJECT)
                                            )
                    );
```